# Optaplanner Constraint streams score calculation questions

Tags: optaplanner

-----------------------------------document-------------------------------

Constraint streams are a Functional Programming form of incremental score calculation in plain Java that is easy to read, write and debug. The API should feel familiar if you’ve worked with Java 8 Streams or SQL.

The ConstraintStreams/ConstraintProvider API is an ongoing project. It works but it has many API gaps. Therefore, it is not rich enough yet to handle complex constraints. Constraint justifications may not function properly.

6.1. Introduction
Using Java 8’s Streams API, we could implement an easy score calculator that uses a functional approach:

```
private int doNotAssignAnn() {
    int softScore = 0;
    schedule.getShiftList().stream()
            .filter(Shift::isEmployeeAnn)
            .forEach(shift -> {
                softScore -= 1;
            });
    return softScore;
}
```

However, that scales poorly because it doesn’t do an incremental calculation: When the planning variable of a single Shift changes, to recalculate the score, the normal Streams API has to execute the entire stream from scratch. The ConstraintStreams API enables you to write similar code in pure Java, while reaping the performance benefits of incremental score calculation. This is an example of the same code, using the Constraint Streams API:

```
private Constraint doNotAssignAnn(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Shift.class)
            .filter(Shift::isEmployeeAnn)
            .penalize("Don't assign Ann", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
}
```

This constraint stream iterates over all instances of class Shift in the problem facts and planning entities in the planning problem. It finds every Shift which is assigned to employee Ann and for every such instance (also called a match), it adds a soft penalty of 1 to the overall score.

-----------------------------------document-------------------------------

**My question is:**

**As a planning entity, if Shift is allocated to Ann for the first time, a soft penalty of adding 1 to the total score will be imposed.
If the second iteration of the optimal solution has a total score of 0 and is assigned to Ann2, no soft penalty will be applied, but the total score of the last time plus 1 soft penalty, how does it become 0?**

Comment: Try using `ScoreManager.getSummary()` or `ScoreManager.explainScore()` to understand how the total is 0 soft.

Comment: Other things to verify, just in case: turn on FULL_ASSERT temporarly, to rule out score corruption as a cause. And you can also turn on TRACE logging to see every decision that OptaPlanner makes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I also saw this part of the logic in the source code. Thank you